# finding standard deviation in csv file

Tags: java, file, csv, streamwriter, opencsv

i am trying to find [standard deviation](http://www.managers-net.com/stddev.html)(σ = √[(Σ(x - MEAN))2 ÷ n]) of single extracted column of csv file.csv file contain around 45000 instance and 17 attribute saperated with ';'.
for finding standard deviation it need  MEAN value in every iteration of while loop for substact with Xi. so i think MEAN need before while loop iteration for find standard deviation.but i dont know how to do this or is there any way to do this. am getting stuck here. then i had puted code for replace old Xi with new Xi. and then write(generate) new csv file.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;

public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String filename = "ly.csv";
        File file = new File(filename);
        BufferedWriter writer = null;

   try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("bank-full_updated.csv"));
       } 
   catch (IOException e) {
        } 
   try {

            double Tuple,avg;
            double temp;
            Tuple = 0; 
            double stddev=0;

             Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
            inputStream.next();
            while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
            String data1 = inputStream.next();                
            String[] values = data1.split(";");
            double Xi = Double.parseDouble(values[1]);
           //now finding standard deviation

            temp1 +=  (Xi-MEAN);                
           // temp2=(temp1*temp1);
           // temp3=(temp2/count);
           // standard deviation=Math.sqrt(temp3);
            Xi=standard deviation * Xi

           //now replace  new Xi to original values1
            values[1] = String.valueOf(Xi);

           // iterate through the values and build a string out of them for write a new file
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String newData = sb.toString();

      for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                sb.append(values[i]);
        if (i < values.length - 1) {
                sb.append(";");
           }
           }
            // get the new string
            System.out.println(sb.toString());

            writer.write(sb.toString()+"\n");
            }

            writer.close();

            inputStream.close();
          }

       catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }    

    }
}
```

Comment: This is a relatively simple mathematical problem, not a programming problem.  Work out the mathematics (in a way you actually understand) first.  (I'm pretty sure the formula on that page you reference is wrong, BTW.)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to calculate the standard deviation in a single pass. Professor Donald Knuth has an algorithm that does it using the Kahan summation. Here is the paper: http://researcher.ibm.com/files/us-ytian/stability.pdf

[Here](http://www.strchr.com/standard_deviation_in_one_pass) is another way but it suffers from rounding errors:

```
double std_dev2(double a[], int n) {
    if(n == 0)
        return 0.0;
    double sum = 0;
    double sq_sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
       sum += a[i];
       sq_sum += a[i] * a[i];
    }
    double mean = sum / n;
    double variance = sq_sum / n - mean * mean;
    return sqrt(variance);
}
```